# aptitude search cannot display origin nor sources nor architecture of installed packages

Tags: 16.04, aptitude

I'm trying to list all packages (and their respective repositories) from other sources than the main/restricted/universe/multiverse.

First I've typed that command to list those packages :

```bash
$ aptitude search -F '%p' '!?origin(Ubuntu) ( ?architecture(amd64) | ?architecture(all) ) ?installed' | head
albert                                                                          
brave-browser                                                                   
brave-keyring                                                                   
browsh                                                                          
cdda2wav                                                                        
cdrecord                                                                        
dockmanager                                                                     
e2fsprogs-l10n                                                                  
ffmbc                                                                           
firefox-esr
```

But if I add `'%e'` or `'%E'` or `'%O'` to the `-F` argument, the `aptitude` immediately returns ... nothing :

```bash
$ aptitude search -F '%p %O' '!?origin(Ubuntu) ( ?architecture(amd64) | ?architecture(all) ) ?installed' | head
$
```

Is this an aptitude bug ?

Comment: Don't you want `!( ?origin(ubuntu) | ?origin(debian) )` or `( !?origin(ubuntu) !?origin(debian) )` (de Morgan's rule - NOT (a OR b) == (NOT a AND NOT b)?

Comment: @steeldriver You're absolutely right :) Fixed.

Comment: Hmm... confirmed the behavior in a 16.04 WSL system (aptitude 0.7.4) whereas my regular 18.04 box (aptitude 0.8.10) appears to handle `%e` / `%E` fine

Comment: So according to the changelog (`apt-get changelog aptitude` on the 18.04 box), *"Add format strings for Source (%E), Architecture (%e) and Origin (%O)"* happened in 0.7.5-1 - so my guess is the version on your system is earlier and simply bails when passed a format specifier that it doesn't understand

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks. Can you convert your comment to an answer ?

Comment: Thanks - done. If that's the *correct* answer then arguably yes it was a bug (it really ought to produce an informative error, rather than simply bailing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the changelog from my 18.04 box, I can see:

> ```
> aptitude (0.7.5-1) unstable; urgency=low
>
>   * New upstream release. Please see /usr/share/aptitude/NEWS for a change
>     log with more details.
>
>     - New features:
> <snip>
>       * Add format strings for Source (%E), Architecture (%e) and
>         Origin (%O) (Closes: #248561, #604982, #760608)
> <snip>
> ```

The version of aptitude in 16.04 appears to be 0.7.4, predating these additions.

So it looks like your `aptitude search -F '%p %e' ...` command is (rather unsportingly) simply bailing when it gets a format specifier that it doesn't understand.

Comment: Thanks. BTW : I just found a Launchpad PPA repository to update aptitude on Ubuntu Xenial (only) : [Launchpad ppa:savoury1/apt-xenial repository](https://launchpad.net/~savoury1/+archive/ubuntu/apt-xenial)
Just tried it, now `aptitude search -F '%O'` works fine :)